# change ajaxq url from another ajaxq

Tags: jquery, jquery-ajaxq

Am using ajaxq http://foliotek.github.io/AjaxQ/ to fire two sequential requests.

I would like to change the url of the second ajaxq with data from the first.
But, I only want the first request to run if x_id passed to func is blank.
Have tried nesting ajax requests - but this means both are always run.
The issue is, the urls are set when the page loads and I cannot get them to be dynamic - please advise TQ

```
$.fn.loadrecord = function(x_id) {
//run first ajaxq if x_id is blank
if (x_id == '') {
$.ajaxq ("q1", {
    url: 'findid.php',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){x_id = data}
})
}
//run second 
$.ajaxq ("q1", {
    url: 'somepage.php?id='+x_id,
    cache: false
})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the solution even without using AJAXQ. Simply modify your code as below.

```
$.fn.loadrecord = function(x_id) {

    function somePage(identifier) {
        //run second 
        $.ajax ({
            url: 'somepage.php?id='+ identifier,
            cache: false
        })
    }


    if (x_id == '') {
        $.ajaxq ("q1", {
            url: 'findid.php',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){somePage(data);}
        })
    } else {
        somePage(x_id);
    }
}
```